# How do I document a Rest parameter providing another type (MyClass vs. String)?

Tags: java, springdoc

In Springfox I once used the following syntax to render a String parameter with a full model ([original Github issue](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2523)):

```
@PatchMapping(path="/{objId}")
@ApiImplicitParams(@ApiImplicitParam(name="update", dataType="MyClass")) 
    public ApiResponse<MyClass> updateMyClassInst(@PathVariable String objId, @RequestBody String update) {
```

The reason for this formulation is that if I put `MyClass` as type for the request body I had no way to distinguish when a property has not been updated or when has been set to null, because both would be deserialized to a null field value.

How do I do that with Springdoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This the equivalent code, using OpenAPI 3.

```
@PatchMapping(path="/{objId}")
@RequestBody( content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = MyClass.class)))
public ApiResponse<MyClass> updateMyClassInst(@PathVariable String objId, @RequestBody String update) {
    return null;
}
```

You can have a look at hte migration guide:

- https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html

And the swagger documentation:

- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations

Comment: Ha! Totally missed the `implementation` property, I did not get it when I read the javadoc. Thanks for the links, I did have checked the migration guide, but not the swagger-core docs which I see give more informations.